# Are there some kind of "multialgebras" with terms or equations, where an operation can result with different values in different places?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, logic

Many-valued (multivalent, polivalent) operations are studied in multialgebras.  Applied to a certain value of its argument, a many-valued operation o(x) can result in different values. But in multialgebras, it is required that o(x) gets **same** value everywhere it occurs in a term or equation. Is there any kind of multialgebras where o(x) can get different values at different places in a term or equation? Probably, the question can be formulated also like this: are there approaches in mathematics which use case-sensitive expressions?

I need this, because I believe, this can help in formalizing natural languages in terms of set theory. More specifically, I am treating common names as denotations of classes of things to which they refer. For example, I treat the noun "cat" as denotation of the class of all cats. Next, it sounds natural to treat the English word "a" as name of an "operation of choice", which chooses one element c of class C (here, one cat) - actually, I say that it chooses the singleton {c} (so that this is an operation over classes). Now, regard the sentence

"Pete saw **a cat** and Jane saw **a cat**, but those were different cats"

In this sentence **a cat** in the first case and **a cat** in the second case are different.

Another example is from computer science. Suppose, in a statement of programming language we used twice the expression "TimeStamp()", which is a "command" to print current time. We can treat TimeStamp() as a 0-operands multi-valued operation, and it definitely gets different values at different places it is used in an expression. So, we have same phenomenon as above.

Is there any mathematical treatment of this phenomena?